# Non-separable non-postliminal $C^*$-algebra with injective $\pi\mapsto\ker\pi$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

It is known that for a postliminal/GCR $C^*$-algebra the map $\pi\mapsto\ker\pi$ from (equivalence classes of) irreducible representations to their kernels is injective. If the algebra is separable, then the converse is also known to be true.

**Questions:**

1. Does there exist a non-separable non-postliminal $C^*$-algebra with injective $\pi\mapsto\ker\pi$?
2. Does there exist a simple such algebra?

Thank you.

Comment: Under additional set-theoretic assumptions, Akemann and Weaver demonstrated the existence of a unital Cstar algebra that has only one irrep up to unitary equivalence; it seems to me that such a beast must be simple, and it can't be separable or Type I by classical results

Comment: (This is merely a comment rather than an answer since I expect Nik Weaver can turn up to give a better answer :) )

Comment: Yes, I can't find a simplicity argument in that paper.

Comment: The converse of what? the main statement is not written as an implication. You mean that for a C$^*$-algebra, postliminal implies the given injectivity property? Also, a simple C$^*$-algebra with the given injectivity property means a C$^*$-algebra with only 1 or 2 irreducible representations up to equivalence, if I'm correct...?

Comment: YCor, 2 irreducibles? Where from? If there is exactly 1 primitive ideal then the injectivity implies that there is 1 equivalence class of irreducibles.

Comment: It appears that the answer to your first question is unknown.  In the (recent) second edition of Pedersen's "C*-algebras and their automorphism groups" the editors write that your question 1 "remains mysterious."  This is in Section 6.8.9.  They expand on their statement in the following section 6.9.